# 7 - Add CSS to a LIST items in a block

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm trying to display a block on a left side bar with few links. I've created a block and it shows up with the links but NO CSS applied:

```
<div class="vertical-tabs">
    <ul class="ul.vertical-tabs-list">
        <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="itemInfo">Site Info</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="jobs">Career</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="aboutus">About Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I check the elements in UI, it doesn't show the vertical-tabs class being applied.

I'm not looking for any custom form. I need to know how the CSS should be applied in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: example: https://jsfiddle.net/0c4ap3kh/

Comment: You may have a text-format applied that strips out certain html elements.

Comment: Are you creating the block in a module, or from the user interface?

Comment: Creating a block from the interface. There is no custom form/code.

Answer (score 2):

There's a template hook for this: `template_preprocess_block`

Use `$variables['classes_array']` to add classes to the block.

Comment: To add the template hook, I should have custom code written. That's not the case here. I'm using a user interface to create a new block. So I'm not sure on how to add this hook in interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$block['content']['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module','mymodule') . '/mymodule.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for custom block

```
function my_module_block_view($delta = '')
{
  if($delta == 'my_module_delta')
  {
    drupal_add_js('path/to/file.js');
    drupal_add_css('path/to/file.css');
    $block = array
    (
      'subject' => t('My block title'),
      'content' => '<p>' . t('This is some text that will go in the block.') . '</p>',
    );
    return $block;
  }
}
```